# How to choose high frequency inductors for high voltage line filtering?

Tags: filter, inductor, three-phase, bridge-rectifier

I saw these [inductors](https://www.rencousa.com/sites/default/files/productfamilies/pdfs/RL-1294.pdf) 680 uH (RL-1294-680) in each power line like shown below. The line to line voltage is 480 VAC. The inductor used has a saturation current of 280 mA. So I suppose I shouldn't reach that point. What should I take into consideration when choosing inductors for this application? In this example, the designer chose 680 uH high frecuency inductors in each power line. How did he come to that conclusion?

[image]

Comment: Magnetics vendors are the worst when it comes to providing clear specs for their products. What the hell does "high frequency" even mean in this datasheet? 1 kHz? 100 kHz? Given the mechanical size of this part, I'm pretty confident it isn't 100 MHz, but what the heck does it actually mean?

Comment: Also, notice note 5 on the datasheet: Suggested maximum voltage 100 V. If you want to use these parts in a 480 V application, you should contact the vendor and see what you're getting into.

Comment: In my case I would choose another inductor. What would you suggest in this application? I don't want to use this inductor just because that designer did. I don't know his reasons. The bridge rectifier is going to supply a low power circuit, that's why I guess he chose a 280 mA inductor.

Comment: Probably what he had. Voltage rating does not matter much as the voltage accross it should not be line voltage... I find a lot of power filters like this one are often I'll designed when it comes to spec'ing parts.

Comment: Do you know another part in the market that would do a better job than this one?